# Example of bundle-mapping over $S^4$ with singularity $S^2$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Could anyone give a non-trivial example of a bundle-mapping over $S^4$, i.e. find two complex rank 2 vector bundles $E_0,E_1$ over $S^4$ and a bundle mapping 
$$0\to E_0\overset{v}{\to}E_1\to0$$
such that the singularity set of $v$(where $v$ is not an isomorphic mapping) is equal to the embedding sphere $S^2$ of $S^4$?

Comment: For the point singularity case, there is an example. Since outside the equator $S^3$, $S^4\setminus S^3$ can shrink to points,we can use the standard identification, but near S3S3 we use the coordinate of the point by $(\alpha,\beta)\to\rho(\sqrt{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2})\left(\begin{array}{cc}\alpha&-\bar\beta\\
\beta&\bar\alpha
\end{array}\right)$, where we use the complex coordinate $(\alpha,\beta)$ and $\rho$ is the cut off function near the point, by the partition of unity, we can have a global mapping. But I do not how to give the sphere singularity example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is YES. First of all, notice the following lemma :

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $K$ be a closed subset in $M$. Then, there exist a smooth function $f$ on $M$ such that $f^{-1}(0)=K$.

We can deduce this lemma by using a partition of unity.

Then, for $M=S^4$ and $K=S^2$, you can construct such an example by setting $E_0=E_1=E$ (where $E$ is an arbitrary complex vector bundle) and $v=f\cdot\text{id}$.

Comment: Could you give the reference of that Lemma. Well, I want to find two different vector bundles $E_0,E_1$. But is is also usefull. Thank you for your sharing.@nsmath

Comment: @DLIN For example, see the Theorem 2.29 in a Lee's textbook _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Second Edition_ (available free online). Be careful of the Edition number.